# What's the best way to duplicate a record in a database table using php?

Tags: php, pdo, insert, duplicates

In a dashboard i'm looping through all the products from a table. Sometimes there are similair products with the same details. That's why i want to add a duplicate function. So i don't have to retype all the same fields. The basic idea is having a button printed out next to each row which triggers a duplicate function.

```
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>$row['id']</td><td>$row['name']</td><td>$row['brand']</td><td><button>Duplicate</button></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

I was thinking of connecting a simple insert() function to the button per row.

```
function insert($value1, $value2, $table){
   $stmt->db->prepare("INSERT INTO $table (name, brand) VALUES ($value1, $value2)";
   $stmt->execute();

   return $stmt;
}
```

that uses the $row values except for the id because that's auto incremented.
I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this.

Comment: More context and code please, you mention UI and interface but give no info around that at all, and what you mean by Type? Is this a management table, a view table, does it function by click to edit, button to edit row, insert form, how is current flow ACTUALLY undesirable???

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I added some more code and changed the explanation a bit.

Comment: Thanks for that, i am puzzled what the actual question is??? Yeh, you can create a button that via ajax or hyperlink/http request hits a php or similar page that executes that query. It will work, but i have no idea if it is the 'best way' because its still entirely unclear where this original table is (website you control, html table you input values into, submit form, whatever). Its hard even knowing the question to ask since there is nothing here to let us determine the "best way", what actual way is currently happening, what is the Current Result vs Desired Result???